# Unable to ping switch

Tags: routing, switching, ping

[image: Pinging S1 from PC-B]

Why can't i ping S1 from PC-B, but it's possible to ping PC-A?

```
S1#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1638 bytes
!
version 16.3.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
service password-encryption

hostname S1

enable secret 5 $1$mERr$9cTjUIEqNGurQiFU.ZeCi1

no ip cef

ipv6 unicast-routing

no ipv6 cef

no ip domain-lookup

spanning-tree mode pvst

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/14

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/15

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/16

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/17

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/18

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/19

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/20

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/21

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/22

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/24

interface GigabitEthernet1/1/1

interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2

interface GigabitEthernet1/1/3

interface GigabitEthernet1/1/4

interface Vlan1

 no ip address
 
ipv6 address FE80::1 link-local
 
ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD:1::B/64

ip classless

ip flow-export version 9

banner motd ^CUNAUTHORIZED ACCESS PROHIBITED!^C

line con 0
 password 7 0822455D0A16
 login

line aux 0

line vty 0 4
password 7 0822455D0A16
 login

line vty 5 15
 password 7 0822455D0A16
 login

end
```

Comment: Likely, because S1 doesn't answer to ICMP echo requests, isn't reachable on that side, or it might not have a (default) gateway. Please add the relevant device configurations to your question (using the { } function) to get a definitive answer.

Comment: I added S1 config file. Default gateway is missing i believe?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your switch does not have a route to either subnet that the PCs are on.